# Sorting user's Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, linked-accounts, sorting

On the `users/{user_id}/{username}?tab=accounts` page of a Stack Exchange site, all the linked accounts are displayed.  It appears that they are sorted by the user's reputation on the particular account.

There should be an option to sort the view of a user's Stack Exchange accounts.  It is frustrating for a user with <strike>many</strike> **several** accounts that there is no way to put them in alphabetical order by Site.

Comment: That isn't many accounts. *This* is many accounts: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff?tab=accounts

Comment: @Jon Seigel, Point taken.  See edit.

Comment: +1 I was just about to ask that same thing and found this existing request.

Comment: Agree. I would like to get the music, cycling, and cooking related sites at the top as "favorite accounts" as I more regularly visit those than some other. By the way, it is not just reputation based, but seems to be registration based as well. That applies when two accounts have the same reputation level.

Comment: A sort-of fix, only for local application though (i.e. no-one else will see it on your profile): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279462/how-can-i-sort-the-network-accounts-list