# How can I sort the network accounts list?

Tags: support, user-accounts, sorting, linked-accounts, network-profile

The network accounts list (at `http://stackexchange.com/users/<USER_ID>/?tab=accounts`) is generally sorted by reputation.

How can I sort it by another criteria? eg. when I last visited a site, the number of questions I've asked, etc.

Comment: [Related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96487/sorting-users-stack-exchange-accounts). (Ideally, each user will be able to decide how his/her own accounts will appear to others, and that will be done via the network profile.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @ShadowWizard. I posted this on there too. Agree it is ideal to be implemented network wide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sorting doesn't appear to be integrated by default. However, it's fairly easy to integrate with a custom script.

I've written the below which should do a fairly good job of offering basic sorting options. It's not perfect - especially because there's only so much you can sort dates like '2 years ago'!) but I think it works pretty well.

It will add a sorting bar to the page that looks like this:

[image]

To install, create a bookmark (eg. on your browser's bookmarks bar), copy the entire code below, and paste it into the address of the bookmark. Open your network accounts list, and click the bookmarklet!

```
javascript:
jQuery(".account-container").each(function(){

    dates = jQuery(this).find(".cool:contains(Joined)").text().replace("Joined ", "").replace("last seen ", "").split(", ");
    dates_processed = new Array();

    for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++){

        dates_processed[i] = new Date();

        if(dates[i].indexOf("today") !== -1){
            /* nothing to do, it's today! */
        }else if(dates[i].indexOf("yesterday") !== -1){
            dates_processed[i].setDate(dates_processed[i].getDate() - 1);
        }else if(dates[i].indexOf(" day ago") !== -1 || dates[i].indexOf(" days ago") !== -1){
            dates[i] = dates[i].replace(" day ago", "").replace(" days ago", "");
            dates_processed[i].setDate(dates_processed[i].getDate() - (dates[i] * 1));
        }else if(dates[i].indexOf(" month ago") !== -1 || dates[i].indexOf(" months ago") !== -1){
            dates[i] = dates[i].replace(" month ago", "").replace(" months ago", "");
            dates_processed[i].setDate(dates_processed[i].getDate() - (dates[i] * 31));
        }else if(dates[i].indexOf(" year ago") !== -1 || dates[i].indexOf(" years ago") !== -1){
            dates[i] = dates[i].replace(" year ago", "").replace(" years ago", "");
            dates_processed[i].setDate(dates_processed[i].getDate() - (dates[i] * 366));
        }

    }

    jQuery(this).attr("data-name", jQuery(this).find(".account-site a").text().trim());
    jQuery(this).attr("data-joined", dates_processed[0].getTime());
    jQuery(this).attr("data-last-seen", dates_processed[1].getTime());
    jQuery(this).attr("data-reputation", jQuery(this).find(".cool:contains(reputation)").prev().text());
    jQuery(this).attr("data-gold-badges", jQuery(this).find(".badge1").next().text());
    jQuery(this).attr("data-silver-badges", jQuery(this).find(".badge2").next().text());
    jQuery(this).attr("data-bronze-badges", jQuery(this).find(".badge3").next().text());
    jQuery(this).attr("data-questions", jQuery(this).find(".cool:contains(questions)").prev().text());
    jQuery(this).attr("data-answers", jQuery(this).find(".cool:contains(answers)").prev().text());

});

/* add the sorter div, after removing any that is there already, in case we're running this more than once */

    jQuery(".vcard .sorter").remove();

    jQuery(".vcard").append('\
        <div class="sorter" style="float: left; margin: 1em 0; font-size: .85em;">\
            Sort by: <a data-type="string">name</a> | <a data-type="timestamp">joined</a> | <a data-type="timestamp">last seen</a> | <a>reputation</a> | <a>gold badges</a> | <a>silver badges</a> | <a>bronze badges</a> | <a>questions</a> | <a>answers</a>\
        </div>\
    ');

/* make the update profile info link align with our new sorter */

    jQuery(".default-profile-site").css("margin-top", "1em");

jQuery(".vcard .sorter a").on("click", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery(this)
        .siblings("a") /* return other links to normal state */
            .css("color", "#366FB3")
            .css("font-weight", "normal")
        .end() /* set the clicked link to an active state */
            .css("color", "black")
            .css("font-weight", "bold")
    ;

    attribute_type = "integer"; /* default attribute type */
    if(jQuery(this).attr("data-type")){ attribute_type = jQuery(this).attr("data-type"); }
    account_sorter("data-" + jQuery(this).text().replace(" ", "-"), attribute_type);

});

function account_sorter(attribute_name, attribute_type){

    accounts = jQuery(".account-container");

    accounts.sort(function(account1, account2){

        if(attribute_type == "integer" || attribute_type == "timestamp"){
            attribute1 = parseInt(jQuery(account1).attr(attribute_name).replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
            attribute2 = parseInt(jQuery(account2).attr(attribute_name).replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
            if(isNaN(attribute1)){ attribute1 = -1; }
            if(isNaN(attribute2)){ attribute2 = -1; }
        }

        if(attribute_type == "string" || attribute_type == "timestamp"){
            /* intentionally reverse these so the sorting happens smallest to largest */
            attribute1 = jQuery(account2).attr(attribute_name);
            attribute2 = jQuery(account1).attr(attribute_name);
        }

        if(attribute1 < attribute2){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;

    });

    accounts.detach().appendTo("#content > .contentWrapper");

}

/* set your default sort here */

    jQuery(".vcard .sorter a:contains(answers)").trigger("click");
```

Happy for any suggestions, improvements or bug fixes - feel free to edit the post directly if you're sure what you're changing works.